# TransportError happened when calling softlayer-api

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

It is wired to get an exception at about 7:30am(utc+8) everyday when calling softlayer-api.

TransportError: TransportError(0): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.softlayer.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /xmlrpc/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package (Caused by ProxyEr
ror('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: **503 Service Unavailable**',)))

And I uses a proxy to forward https request to softlayer's server. At first I thougth it is caused by the proxy, but when I looked into the log, it showed every request had been forwarded successfully. So maybe it is caused by the server. Does the server do something so busy at that moment everyday that it fails to server?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any report about this kind of issue nor if the server is busy in SoftLayer's side. but regarding to your issue, it is something related with network issues. It seems that there is something happening with your proxy connection.

First we need to discard if the proxy can be the reason for this issue, it would be very useful if can verify that this issue is reproducible without using a proxy from your side, let me know if you could test it.

If you could check this without proxy, I recommend to submit a ticket for further investigation about this issue.